# Javascript - How to create a independent Variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor

I want to create a variable that could stand independently for every instance. Okay, let's jump to the code directly.

```
var gameData = undefined;

createNewRoom = function() {
 gameData = new myConstructor([]); // it will instantiate a new object for each new room

}

myConstructor = function(data) {
 var _data = data;
 this.object = function() {
  return _data;
 }
}
```

The case is, player A created a room, it runs smoothly **until**, player B or player C and etc created a room, because the `gameData` variable is being shared. How to make the `gameData` variable runs independently? In other words, global variable that runs independently for each instance?

Or am I doing it in a bad way?

Comment: One way is to have `gameData` defined as an array e.g., gamesData[], then have each players gameData in an element of array.

Comment: yup, i were using it before, but the problem is the array structure always change (deleted index, additional index), i got the index problem, because the index dynamically changing

Answer (score 0):

Hi try following code.

```
createNewRoom = function() {
 this.gameData = new myConstructor([]); // it will instantiate a new object for each new room

}

myConstructor = function(data) {
 var _data = data;
 this.object = function() {
  return _data;
 }
}
```

This will help you.

Comment: it doesn't work, if you want to call it from another function

Comment: how you call it from other function??
by creating object of createNewRoom class .

Comment: just call the gameData variable

Comment: For this you will need to create Static variable which will be common for all instances of createNewRoom class.

It not possible to create global variable which will work independently for other instances.